# Why does my windows 7 install(s) randomly use the vista startup screen?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

It seems that in a few of several windows 7 installs i've seen so far, it will use the vista startup screen as opposed to the new windows 7 one. Nothing else is wrong, it just uses the old one. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had that same thing happen here, and although I don't really have a clue, I thought it might have something to do with the screen size or something. I get the fancy boot animation on my desktop which have a 1680x1050 screen, while my laptop which has 1024x600 gets a boring one.

Comment: Certainly a possibility, maybe the new boot graphic isn't compatible with various screen resolutions... *shrugs*

Comment: Yeah, watched an interview about it a while ago where they said they had done some work on it and among other things managed to increase the resolution. Think it was to 1024x768. Maybe it falls back if it screen size is smaller than that.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be a problem with the graphical drivers. You'll see Windows 7 being extra careful when booting in to safe mode or repair mode, it uses the "old" vista style loader instead of the new moving dots loader..

I always figured the old loader ran in a simple VGA mode (hence the crappy resolution) while the new loader uses a smarter driver to display in a higher resolution.

So it might be about the graphical card in those computers.

Comment: I have an NVidia 8800 GTS in this computer.

Comment: Sorry to be so blunt, i really didn't mean it that way!

Answer (score 0):

Did you use an older version of VistaBootPro or a similar boot manager utility? They are often not compatible with Windows 7, and will use the Vista boot loader instead of the Win7 one.

Comment: Hmm. I used EasyBCD on one machine but on others (possibly low-end systems) use it.